# Enum syntax usage in Java

Tags: java, enums

Right now I'm trying to make a toy TicTacToe program in java.

```
public class Board {
private enum Slot {
    UNFILLED, FIRSTPLAYER, SECONDPLAYER
}

private Slot[][] board = {{"UNFILLED", "UNFILLED", "UNFILLED"}, {"UNFILLED", "UNFILLED", "UNFILLED"}, {"UNFILLED", "UNFILLED", "UNFILLED"}};
```

I declare an enum called Slot, and I'm trying to populate my board with this enum. What is the proper syntax for doing this?

Comment: You're putting Strings in your array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either:

```
private Slot[][] board = {{Slot.UNFILLED, ...
```

or

```
private Slot[][] board = {{UNFILLED, ...
```

in which case you need to add a static import: `import static your.package.Board.Slot.*;`